# WSO2 ESB REST API Chaining issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am facing some issues when doing service chaining is WSO2 ESB. Below is the xml file.
Following is my use case. I need to call Service 1, get the response, do validation check on it and then call Service 2. Through the below code I am successfully able to call Service 1. For the service two request, I have hard coded the request in the payload. Issue is coming when setting the header parameters. The header properties are not getting set due to which call to Service 2 is not going. For testing purpose I have kept both the URLs same.

Please let me know the following:
1. How to set HTTP Header values.
2. Is there a way to persist the Initial input request and then use it in the second Service call.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your synapse configs are not there I'll answer your question.

1. You can do this two ways. One is by using the Header Mediator. You can reffer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator#HeaderMediator-Example2-HTTPheaders) Doc. Example code below,

```xml
<header name="Accept" value="image/jpeg" scope="transport"/>
```

The second approach is using the property mediator, You can set the Header value and set the scope to transport. So the Header property will be added.

2. What you simply need to do it assign the original request content to a Property, so you can use it later. There are many ways to do this, Following example is by using the enrich mediator

```xml
<enrich>
<source type="body" clone="true"/>
<target type="property" property="request"/>
</enrich>
```